# Puts and Gets in c++

Tags: c++

I know what puts and gets do, but I don't understand the meaning of this code.

```
int main(void) {
    char s[20];   
    gets(s); //Helloworld
    gets(s+2);//dog
    sort(s+1,s+7);
    puts(s+4);
}
```

Could you please help me to understand?

Comment: Try using debugger, it's really good in this sort of problems

Comment: I am using cpp.sh online thats why i cant

Comment: Some debugging is always available. You could, for example, write the `s` value after each line

Comment: Can you please line by line explain

Comment: Take out a piece of paper. Draw 20 squares. Fill in the values you read (and sort) at each step.

Comment: Which `sort` function is that calling? Aside from the general advice of "Never, ever, under any circumstances, use `gets` - it's the single worst function ever published.

Comment: Actually this code is so terrible that you better not look at it ... But anyway: 's' is an array with enough space to store 20 characters. You can access 's' like a pointer, so, 's + 2' accesses the third character in the array etc.

Comment: what will s+4 return?

Comment: _"I am using cpp.sh online thats why i cant"_ Install a compiler on to your computer.

Comment: @LalaAli: s+4 is the same as &s[4]: it returns the address at the fifth position because indices start counting from 0.

Comment: @MatsPetersson: its's still competing with the better known strcpy and scanf (in combination with %s) for that position.

Comment: @stefaanv: Agree that `scanf` can be as bad, but for both of those, the user CAN mitigate the risk of buffer-overrun by  using a length modifier for `%s` or checking the length beforehand, as opposed to `gets` that just simply keeps writing to the argument until something goes bang!

Answer (score 2):

Draw it on paper, along these lines.

At first, twenty uninitialised elements:

```
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |
```

`gets(s)`:

```
|H|e|l|l|o|w|o|r|l|d|0| | | | | | | | | |
```

`gets(s+2)`:

```
|H|e|d|o|g|0|o|r|l|d|0| | | | | | | | | |
     ^
     |
    s+2
```

`sort(s+1, s+7)`:

```
|H|0|d|e|g|o|o|r|l|d|0| | | | | | | | | |
   ^           ^
   |           |
  s+1         s+7
```

`puts(s+4)`:

```
|H|0|d|e|g|o|o|r|l|d|0| | | | | | | | | |
         ^
         |
        s+4
```

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to say about the code is that it is very bad.  Luckily, it is short but it is vulnerable, unmaintainable and error prone.

However, since the previous is not really an answer, let's go through the code, assuming the standard include files were used and "using namespace std;":

- char s[20];

This declares an array of 20 characters with the intent of filling it with a null-terminated string.  If somehow, the string becomes larger, you're in trouble

- gets(s); //Helloworld

This reads in a string from stdin.  No checks can be done on the size.  The comment assumes it will read in Helloworld, which should fit in s.

- gets(s+2);//dog

This reads in a second string from stdin, but it will overwrite the previous string starting from the third character.  So if the comment is write, s will contain the null-terminated string "Hedog".

- sort(s+1,s+7);

This will sort the characters in asserting ascii value from the second up to the seventh character.  With the given input, we already have a problem that the null-character is on the sixth position so it will be part of the sorted characters and thus will be second, so the null-terminated string will be "H".

- puts(s+4);

Writes out the string from the fifth position on, so until the null-charater that was read in for "Helloworld", but then overwritten and half-sorted.  Of course input can be anything, so expect surprises.

Answer (score -2):

```
  gets(s); //Helloworld   -- reads a string from keyboard to s
  gets(s+2);//dog         -- reads a string from keyboard to s started with char 2
  sort(s+1,s+7);          -- sorts s in interval [1, 7]
  puts(s+4);              -- writes to console s from char 4
```

gets(s); //Helloworld   --> s=**Helloworld**

gets(s+2);//dog         --> s=He**dog**

sort(s+1,s+7);          --> s=H**dego**

puts(s+4);              --> console=Hdeg**o**

Comment: My answer doesn't seem to agree, because I took the null-character into account while sorting (maybe we're thinking of a different version of sort) and puts starts at position 5, so even with sorting upto the null-character, output would be "o".

Comment: No. `std::gets` doesn't, magically, clear the buffer, so, the string, in array, after each step, would look as follows (using `_` character to denote `\0` character, for better readability): (1) `Helloworld_`; (2) `Hedog_orld_`; (3) `H_degoorld_`; And the `puts` would output `goorld`. Working example: [here](https://ideone.com/Ln5NJ6).